# Open covers by ind-affine ind-schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

Many apologies if this is totally standard! I couldn't find it in the literature.

*Background definitions:*

- A presheaf $X: \textbf{Aff}^\text{op} \to \textbf{Set}$ is an **ind-scheme** if it is a filtered colimit of schemes, where we regard a scheme as a presheaf via the Yoneda embedding (and then restrict to affine schemes), and the colimit is taken in the category $\text{Psh}(\textbf{Aff})$ of presheaves (i.e. the colimit is taken "pointwise"). One can impose the condition that all of the transition maps are closed immersions, and then call the result a **strict ind-scheme**.
- Let's say that $X$ is an **ind-affine ind-scheme** if it is a filtered colimit of affine schemes. (Side question: Is this the right terminology? It seems there are several distinct notions with this name in the literature.)

*Context:*

- It is well known that a presheaf $X \in \text{Psh}(\textbf{Aff})$ is represented by a scheme if and only if it satisfies the following two conditions: 1) $X$ is a Zariski sheaf and, 2) There is a covering of $X$ by open affine subfunctors.
- Every ind-scheme is a Zariski sheaf (in fact satisfies the sheaf condition for the fpqc topology).
- The affine Grassmannian (which is an ind-scheme) admits an open cover by ind-affine ind-schemes. See, e.g. the extremely helpful paper by Timo Richarz "Basics on Affine Grassmannians".

*Question:*

Is there a similar characterization for (strict or otherwise) ind-schemes? I.e. is something like the following true: a presheaf $X$ is an ind-scheme if and only if 1) $X$ is a Zariski sheaf and, 2) $X$ admits a covering by open subfunctors which are ind-affine ind-schemes? Is it at least sufficient? If not, is there a name for the presheaves that satisfy this property?

Comment: If you are a filtered colimit of schemes, aren't you also a filtered colimit of affine schemes?

Comment: @Asvin I think you are conflating two different kinds of colimits there. It is true that a scheme is a filtered colimit of affine schemes – in the category of schemes or in the category of Zariski sheaves. But I don't think it is true in the category of presheaves. Otherwise we could just be studying pro-rings instead of schemes.

Comment: Ah, I see. That's an interesting difference!

Comment: @ZhenLin Do you have a reference for the "It is true" claim?  I am having difficulty writing $\mathbb{P}^1$ as a filtered colimit of affine schemes.

Comment: Ah, I confused cofiltered and filtered there, oops.